# iTerm automatically opening when I download something in Chrome

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I know this is a strange one... On my Macbook when using Chrome after I download a file (any file) after about a second iTerm opens up, front and center with focus. This happens if iTerm is open, minimized, or even if its not running at all.

Any ideas?

Update:
Not specifically related to Chrome in anyway. It seems that when a new file is created on my Desktop or in Downloads iTerm opens on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Ug. I had an automator script that opened iterm when I added something to my desktop. Answering my own question here.